# GPS Location Always Shows Location as zero

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gps, locationmanager

I am sending the location of the user by email on button click. The doInBackground of the AsyncTask is given below.

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean status = false;
    try {
    double latitude=0;
    double longitude=0;
    GPSTracker gps=new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){
        latitude=gps.getLatitude();
        longitude=gps.getLongitude();
    }
    String mapUrl= "https://www.google.co.in/maps/@"+latitude+","+longitude+",17z";
    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(
        "myemail@gmail.com", "password",
        getApplicationContext());
    status = sender.sendMail(" Subject ", "\nLocation : "+mapUrl,"myemail@gmail.com",
         "anothermail@gmail.com");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return status;
}
```

But always returns Location as 0,0

`GPSTracker.java`

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
// getting GPS status
isGPSEnabled = locationManager
    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
// getting network status
isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
    // no network provider is enabled
    } else {
    this.canGetLocation = true;
    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
        Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    }
    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
    if (isGPSEnabled) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,                    
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
        Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The log shows

```
05-16 22:01:30.449: W/System.err(12459): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-16 22:01:30.489: W/System.err(12459): at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
05-16 22:01:30.489: W/System.err(12459): at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:198)
05-16 22:01:30.489: W/System.err(12459): at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:198)
05-16 22:01:30.499: W/System.err(12459): at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:604)
05-16 22:01:30.499: W/System.err(12459): at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:471)
05-16 22:01:30.509: W/System.err(12459): at com.package.utils.GPSTracker.getLocation(GPSTracker.java:65)
05-16 22:02:07.309: W/System.err(12459): at com.package.utils.GPSTracker.getLocation(GPSTracker.java:65)
05-16 22:02:07.309: W/System.err(12459): at com.package.utils.GPSTracker.<init>(GPSTracker.java:44)
05-16 22:02:07.309: W/System.err(12459):    at com.webnamaste.ulrasoundindia.MainActivity$SendMailTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:255)
05-16 22:02:07.319: W/System.err(12459): at com.package.ulrasoundindia.MainActivity$SendMailTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-16 22:02:07.319: W/System.err(12459): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-16 22:02:07.319: W/System.err(12459): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-16 22:02:07.319: W/System.err(12459): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-16 22:02:07.319: W/System.err(12459): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
05-16 22:02:07.339: W/System.err(12459): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-16 22:02:07.339: W/System.err(12459): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-16 22:02:07.349: W/System.err(12459): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Is the gps icon blinking or is it fixed while running the app???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `doInBackground` of `AsyncTask` is executed on the background thread, it's not a main (UI) thread. Here you can have 3 solutions:

1. Move getting GPS coordinates procedure to the `onPreExecute` and pass the result to the `doInBackground`
2. Call `runOnUiThread` at the `doInBackground` for invoking `GPSTracker`, this is ugly solution.
3. Use the combination of `Looper.prepare();` and `Looper.loop();`

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

Comment: Moved getting GPS coordinates procedure to the onPreExecute. it now blinks the gps but location is still 0. The google maps of the Mobile shows the correct location.

Comment: i am getting
NETWORK LOCATION MANAGER = NOT NULL,
NETWORK LOCATION = NULL,
GPS LOCATION MANAGER = NOT NULL,
GPS LOCATION = NULL.
while checking the if s in the GPSTracker.java

Comment: is the context passed should be MainActivity.this or getApplicationContext() or getBaseContext()

Comment: @user3301269 `getApplicationContext()` is better, to avoid memory leaks, but it's not the source of the problem. Are you sure your `GPSTracker` has no bugs?

Comment: the class is copy pasted from `androidhive.com`. no bug in that code i think. is it a problem with the device i am testing. should i test on another device or in emulator. but it is `showing exact location in google maps`

Comment: @user3301269 does `canGetLocation()` return `true`? if not, that is why you get default values. try to debug your app

Comment: i debugged. canGetLocation() returns true. the location got from location manager is null. what do i do?

Comment: source not found ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.getLastKnownLocation(String) line: 889 on debug

Comment: @user3301269 sometimes `getLastKnownLocation` can return `null`, because provider is not ready or there is no last known location. you can search for a posts how to handle such cases

Answer (score 0):

You are trying show some data in the gui app, in the doInBackgrund(), the solution is
put Looper.preprare() in the first line in doInBackgrund().

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Looper.prepare();//This code
boolean status = false;
try {
double latitude=0;
double longitude=0;
GPSTracker gps=new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
if(gps.canGetLocation()){
    latitude=gps.getLatitude();
    longitude=gps.getLongitude();
}
String mapUrl= "https://www.google.co.in/maps/@"+latitude+","+longitude+",17z";
GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(
    "myemail@gmail.com", "password",
    getApplicationContext());
status = sender.sendMail(" Subject ", "\nLocation : "+mapUrl,"myemail@gmail.com",
     "anothermail@gmail.com");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return status;
}
```